# How to create logging for ECS Task definition?

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS CDK. I am trying to create logging for my task definition. I have below code.

```
logDetail = logs.LogGroup(
    self,
    "MerchWebServicesLogGroup",
    log_group_name="/projects/merchwebserviceslog/apiservices",
    retention=logs.RetentionDays.SIX_MONTHS,
    removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
)

task_definition = ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(
    self, "TaskDef", execution_role=MWSECSTaskExecutionRole
)


container = task_definition.add_container(
    "mw-service",
    image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry(
        "187628286232.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/location/location-service:latest"
    ),
    memory_limit_mib=3072,
    logging=ecs.LogDriver.aws_logs(stream_prefix="mwservice", log_group=logDetail),
)
```

Which generates

```yaml
    TaskDef54694570:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
          ContainerDefinitions:
            - Essential: true
              Image: 123.dkr.amazonaws.com/location/location-service:latest
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awslogs
                Options:
                  awslogs-group:
                    Ref: MerchWebServicesLogGroup94598F8F
                  awslogs-stream-prefix: mwservice
                  awslogs-region: ap-southeast-2
              Memory: 3072
              Name: mw-service
              PortMappings:
                - ContainerPort: 44319
                  HostPort: 0
                  Protocol: tcp
           ExecutionRoleArn:
             Fn::GetAtt:
              - TaskDefExecutionRoleB4775C97
               - Arn
          Family: locationagentcdkTaskDef1C411958
          NetworkMode: bridge
          RequiresCompatibilities:
            - EC2
          TaskRoleArn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - TaskDefTaskRole1EDB4A67
              - Arn
    
    TaskDefExecutionRoleB4775C97:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action: sts:AssumeRole
                Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Version: "2012-10-17"
        Metadata:
          aws:cdk:path: location-agent-cdk/TaskDef/ExecutionRole/Resource
      TaskDefExecutionRoleDefaultPolicy0DBB737A:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
        Properties:
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
            Version: "2012-10-17"
          PolicyName: TaskDefExecutionRoleDefaultPolicy0DBB737A
          Roles:
            - Ref: TaskDefExecutionRoleB4775C97
```

The Problem is I do not want to pass any ExecutionRoleArn. If I pass execution role ARN I start getting  error 'Failed to initialize logging driver' otherwise works fine. Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks